# AngularJS: How would I show a " ^ " arrow only when they click the Price label to sort by Price

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I only want to display the span tag when they click the " Price " label to sort by lowest to highest price of items

```
<th id="tbl-labels" ng-click="orderByMe('price')">Price<span id="small">lowest price</span></th>
```

here is the full controller code

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="outPopUp">
    <svg></svg>
    </div>
    <p id="search-txt">Search an item</p>
    <input id="rounded" text" ng-model="searchfor" />
    <div id="container">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th id="tbl-labels" ng-click="orderByMe('product')">Product</th>
            <th id="tbl-labels" ng-click="orderByMe('price')">Price<span id="small">lowest price</span></th>
            <th id="tbl-labels">Link</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr-items" ng-repeat="deal in deals | filter:searchfor | orderBy:myOrderBy">
            <td id="product">{{deal.product}}</td>
            <td id="price">${{deal.price}}</td>
            <td id="url">{{deal.link}}</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You could have a flag in the model like `isOrdered` and then ng show if that is true

Answer (score 1):

Your span id="small" must have a ng-show or ng-hide and the expression should be updated when orderByMe is executed.

```
<th id="tbl-labels" ng-click="orderByMe('price')">Price<span ng-show="isLowestToHigher" id="small">lowest price</span></th>
```

in your scope I think you have something like

```
function orderByMe(property) {
...
...
  if(property === 'price') {
     scope.isLowestToHigher = !scope.isLowestToHigher
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all id rename the id "small"  to something more representing of what you're trying to accomplish. something like "filter-by-price".

Then in your orderByMe function:

```
function orderByMe(property) {
...
...
  if(property === 'price') {
     $("filter-by-price").addClass("lowtohigh");
  }
}
```

Then in your css you would do something like:

```
#filter-by-price .lowtohigh::after { 
    content: " ^"; 
}
```

You could also change your function to toggle filtering and you'd just add another class to handle that.

```
#filter-by-price .hightolow::after { 
    content: " ˅"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable $scope.clickedValue=false;
Make it true when the price is clicked and then use ng-show directive.

```
<th id="tbl-labels" ng-click="orderByMe('price')">Price<span ng-show="clickedPrice" id="small">lowest price</span></th>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ` $scope.clickedPrice=false;

    $scope.orderByMe = function(q) {
        this.myOrderBy = q;

        if ($scope.myOrderBy = 'price') {
            this.clickedPrice = true;
        } else {

            $scope.clickedPrice =false; 
        }

    };`